# ApplicationBar Foreground color not applying

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, application-bar

I am working on Windows Phone 8 application.

I have Application Bar with icon, I have set the Background and Foreground color to the icons as well.

```
ApplicationBar.BackgroundColor // Orange

ApplicationBar.ForegroundColor // White
```

So now the Application bar looks like this :

[image]

Now my `phone theme settings` i have set the `Accent color as pink` so when i tap on the icon it looks like this :

[image]

But when i tap on the icon i want the effect to be is like this, even if my Phone setting `Accent color is pink or some other color` and background is set to `light or dark`.

[image]

Comment: you can change the image on button click to make the effect

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to change the behaviour of the ApplicationBar in the way you describe.
The ApplicationBar is not a regular control and it is not possible to alter it's behaviour in this way.

If you really, really want to get the behaviour you're after you'll need to create your own replacement for the ApplicationBar.

Comment: Say if i give foreground color as brown then on tap on icon and its with brown color only, but why its not same case with white color ?